# How to pass arguments with space by environment variable?

Tags: bash, shell

On bash shell, I want to pass argument by environment variable.
like this...

```
$ export DOCKER_OPTIONS="-p 9200:9200 -e ES_JAVA_OPTS='-Xmx1g -Xms1g' -d "
$ docker run -d $DOCKER_OPTIONS elasticsearch
```

I expect that "ES_JAVA_OPTS='-Xmx1g -Xms1g'" is passed as an option value of "-e". But I couldn't find a way.

```
$ set -x
$ docker run -d $DOCKER_OPTIONS elasticsearch
+ docker run -d -p 9200:9200 -e 'ES_JAVA_OPTS='\''-Xmx1g' '-Xms1g'\''' elasticsearch
unknown shorthand flag: 'X' in -Xms1g'
```

This separated -Xms1g as an another option.

```
$ docker run -d "$DOCKER_OPTIONS" elasticsearch
+ docker run -d '-p 9200:9200 -e ES_JAVA_OPTS='\''-Xmx1g -Xms1g'\''' elasticsearch
docker: Invalid containerPort: 9200 -e ES_JAVA_OPTS='-Xmx1g -Xms1g'.
```

This bundled the parameters together.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an array to circumvent these awkward parsing problems. Arrays are great because you don't need to do any special quote when defining them. The only place you have to be careful with quotes is when expanding them: always put quotes around `"${array[@]}"`.

```
dockerOptions=(-p 9200:9200 -e ES_JAVA_OPTS='-Xmx1g -Xms1g' -d)
docker run -d "${dockerOptions[@]}" elasticsearch
```

Note that `export` isn't needed since you're passing the options to docker via its command-line rather than as an environment variable.

Also, all uppercase names are reserved for the shell. It's best to avoid them when defining your own variables.